# How can I reverse the loss of window manager pre-set sizes in macOS?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I used to have a feature on my mac hat when a window is dragged to the top, it gets fullscreen. Another tool loved on the menu bar that had a list of around 15 different preset window sizes.

Both of these features are now missing and I do not know how to bring them back.

Can anyone offer advice?

Comment: This isn't a standard feature, but there are utility applications which provide things like this. Did you have one of them installed in the past?

Comment: Yes, this sounds like BetterSnapTool, or similar.

Comment: BetterTouchTool does it. Or I used to have an app, Magnet, that did the same. Double-clicking the title bar (standard macOS feature) usually does it too, but doesn't always completely fill the screen for some reason. Apps seem to have their own preferred (random) aspect ratio.